# Hiding tabs in TabBarViewController Programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tabs, uitabbarcontroller

I have a TabBarViewController that I'd like to make visible/invisible some of the tabs based on some conditions automatically. I tried the following but it did not work. `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?` return nil.

```
class MainPageTabBar: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {

            if let tabBarItem = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[3] {
                tabBarItem.isEnabled = false
            }
        } else {
            if let tabBarItem = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[4] {
                print("I have tabbb")
                tabBarItem.isEnabled = false
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want disabled or remove tab item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your tabbar vc all you need to do that

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
      tabBarController?.delegate = self
      if userStatus == 1 {      //userStatus is sting where check the user status so if userstatus is 1 then tabbar show 4 tabs otherwise tabbar show 3 tabs

            self.viewControllers![0].title = "DASHBOARD"
            self.viewControllers![1].title = "COMMUNITIES"
            self.viewControllers![2].title = "ADMIN ACCOUNTS"
            self.viewControllers![3].title = "REPORTS"
        }else{
            var viewControllers = self.viewControllers
            viewControllers?.remove(at: 2)  // here i'm removing my no 2 tabs which is ADMIN ACCOUNTS you can see in above conditions and then i'm replacing that 2 index with third index as you see
            self.viewControllers = viewControllers
            self.viewControllers![0].title = "DASHBOARD"
            self.viewControllers![1].title = "COMMUNITIES"
            self.viewControllers![2].title = "REPORTS"
        }
}
```

and one more thing this code is for tabbar class.

i'm working on xcode 11.1 so it's work fine for me hope it will work for you.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

set the rootViewController of window as the viewcontroller you want like this:`UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc`